# Family tree created with basic primitives has extra links for child

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using [basic primitives](http://www.basicprimitives.com///) to create family tree. I have problem when i have bigger tree. Then the script is creating a link for child when there aren't any children for that individual. Here is an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6jrS9Pi9g5ucwvaiAvH2?p=preview) of the problem.

Here is the snippet of the code that I'm using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="primitives.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="basicdiagram" style="width: 640px; height: 480px; border-style: dotted; border-width: 1px;">
    </div>

    <script data-require="jquery@1.9.1" data-semver="1.9.1" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery-ui@1.10.4" data-semver="1.10.4" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="primitives.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code is missing. You are just showing some includes.

Comment: Looking at your demo you are using some strange id's eg ( "id": "4fe56e6d-a379-4abf-b015-32455ea845de") in the array -- cant you just use numbers like in the demo here -- http://www.basicprimitives.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=68&Itemid=111&lang=en

Comment: @neuhaus the code is in the plunker

Comment: @Tasos I updated the plunker with ids and fix duplicates errors and not found parents https://plnkr.co/edit/6jrS9Pi9g5ucwvaiAvH2?p=preview

Comment: try inserting the data id in a sequence [1,2,3,4,5,6 .... ] at the moment you have [1,4,5,2,3,7 ..] . not sure if that matters but try that.  -- check top comment here -- http://www.basicprimitives.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=68&Itemid=111&lang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed in 2.1.7 update. Family diagram supports multiple spouses per node, see Johm Green & Victoria. Their spouses are going to be full size when you click and navigate to them.

In the picture below the current node is Jonathan Hitt, so chart shows only its parents, siblings, children and spouses.

http://www.basicprimitives.com/index.php?option=com_local&view=local&Itemid=96&lang=en

[image]

Comment: I added the latest update to plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/6jrS9Pi9g5ucwvaiAvH2?p=preview and it's ok :) thanks